# Count unique values and add result values as new column

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have large csv file and want to build simple ranking:

```
$ cat file.csv
2022-12-01     RED     1     
2022-12-01     RED     1     
2022-12-01     RED     2     
2022-12-01     RED     2     
2022-12-01     RED     2     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     1     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     1     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     2     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     2     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     2     
$ sort file.csv | uniq -c | sort -nr > file_sort.csv
$ cat file_sort.csv 
3 2022-12-01     RED     2     
3 2022-12-01     YELLOW     2     
2 2022-12-01     RED     1     
2 2022-12-01     YELLOW     1
```

I want a result to be added as new column but instead its being added for existing $1 as below:

```
$ cut -f1 file_sort.csv
3 2022-12-01
3 2022-12-01
2 2022-12-01
2 2022-12-01
```

Is there any way to save the value of uniq lines as new column? Like this:

```
$ cut -f1 file_sort.csv
3
3
2
2
```

Comment: Do you want it as a new column added on every line, or do you just want the value and nothing else, the way you show?

Comment: @terdon i want it as new column added on every line

Comment: OK, then please [edit] your question and show us the actual output you want because you are showing something completely different (just one column of output).

Comment: em, I am not? The output I show to you is what I want after using cut. So yes, I want unique value of each line as new column in file_sort.csv file. But after using cut I want it to be a separeted column with values.

Comment: Well, you can get that exact output if there is nothing but a single column in the file. And if that's all you want, why have the rest? Presumably, you want i) all the fields in the file _and_ ii) you want the number of occurrences as the 1st field. It would just be easier and clearer to make that explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like all you want to do is simply move the number from the first field to the last. You don't specify this, but given the `cut` command you show, that should mean that your file is tab-delimited. If so, given that the `uniq -c` output will pad the line with spaces (which you also haven't shown), and will not add a tab after the number of occurrences, you could do something as simple as:

```
$ sort file.csv | uniq -c | sort -nr | perl -pe 's/^\s+(\d+) (.*)/$2\t$1/' 
2022-12-01  YELLOW  2   3
2022-12-01  RED 2   3
2022-12-01  YELLOW  1   2
2022-12-01  RED 1   2
```

Or, in a `sed` that supports `-E`:

```
$ sort file.csv | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed -E 's/^ *([0-9]*) (.*)/\2\t\1/' 
2022-12-01  YELLOW  2   3
2022-12-01  RED 2   3
2022-12-01  YELLOW  1   2
2022-12-01  RED 1   2
```

And, in any sed:

```
$ sort file.csv | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)/\2\t\1/' 
2022-12-01  YELLOW  2   3
2022-12-01  RED 2   3
2022-12-01  YELLOW  1   2
2022-12-01  RED 1   2
```

Alternatively, you could do the counting in `awk` instead, add the field where you want it and the sort on the 4th field:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{ cnt[$0]++ } 
                          END{
                            for(line in cnt){
                              print line,cnt[line]
                            }
                          }' file.csv | sort -nrk4,4 
2022-12-01  YELLOW  2   3
2022-12-01  RED 2   3
2022-12-01  YELLOW  1   2
2022-12-01  RED 1   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

What you want to do is `Bag` elements, in this case the elements are `lines`:

```
~$ raku -e '.say for lines.Bag;'  file
```

Sample Input (tab-separated):

```
2022-12-01     RED     1     
2022-12-01     RED     1     
2022-12-01     RED     2     
2022-12-01     RED     2     
2022-12-01     RED     2     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     1     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     1     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     2     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     2     
2022-12-01     YELLOW     2
```

Sample Output:

```
2022-12-01    RED    2        3
2022-12-01    RED    1        2
2022-12-01    YELLOW    2        3
2022-12-01    YELLOW    1        2
```

Note: a real problem here could be trailing-whitespace. You can add a `trim-trailing` call to get rid of whitespace at the right end of each line:

```
~$ raku -e '.put for lines.map(*.trim-trailing).Bag;' 

#OR

~$ raku -e '.put for lines>>.trim-trailing.Bag;'
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Bag
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

Using the `count-distinct` sub-command of Miller (`mlr`) to count the number of records that have distinct values in the three first fields, assuming the input is tab-delimited and without column headers:

```bash
$ mlr --tsv -N count-distinct -f 1,2,3 file
2022-12-01      RED     1       2
2022-12-01      RED     2       3
2022-12-01      YELLOW  1       2
2022-12-01      YELLOW  2       3
```

The counts are added as a new field at the end of the list of fields. The input does not need to be sorted.

If you want the counts as the first field, then use the `reorder` sub-command.  Note that we may refer to the named field `count` which was created by the `count-distinct` operation, even though the header isn't showing in the output:

```bash
$ mlr --tsv -N count-distinct -f 1,2,3 then reorder -f count file
2       2022-12-01      RED     1
3       2022-12-01      RED     2
2       2022-12-01      YELLOW  1
3       2022-12-01      YELLOW  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting unique lines is easily done with associative arrays idea of awk command:

```
$ awk  '{a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) print a[i]"--->",i}' infile

2---> 2022-12-01     YELLOW     2     
3---> 2022-12-01     RED     2     
2---> 2022-12-01     YELLOW     1     
1---> 2022-12-01     YELLOW     2
2---> 2022-12-01     RED     1
```

Comment: You may have some trailing whitespace in your test data making `2022-12-01 YELLOW 2` show up twice.